# how to restrict input options in form field, in function of value in other field (php mySQL)

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a simple html form. you can choose in field one a country, and in field 2 a city. However, the cities in field 2 can only be the cities of that country...
So once the first field has a value , e.g. Belgium, the list of cities has to be restricted. The countries and cities are in a database, that is no problem. However, how do I refer to the content of the first field without submitting the form?

```
<form action="/index.php" method="post">
    <select id="country" name="country">
        <option>Country</option>
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="The Netherlands">The Netherlands</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <select id="city" name="city">
        <option>City</option>
        <option value="Cologne">Cologne</option>
        <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
        <option value="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
        <option value="Antwerp">Antwerp</option>
        <option value="Brussels">Brussels</option>
        <option value="Rotterdam">Rotterdam</option>    
        <option value="Breda">Breda</option>           
        <option value="Utrecht">Utrecht</option>     
    </select>

    <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
```

I tried $_GET['country'] but it returns always NULL...

Comment: You can do an ajax call when you're selecting an element in the first `<select>` so you can fetch the cities from your database and fill the second `<select>`

Comment: If the number of cities is not to large you could make a separate select for each country and use Javascipt to only show the select for the country that was selected. That would respond faster than an AJAX call to create the second select.

Comment: Or add a class to the options of the second select, so that you could filter them using client-side JS based on that.